# format of rounded large numbers in R

Tags: r, rounding

Starting with R (3.3.1 64bit on Windows) I found out that mean() provides too many fractional digits, so I used round(x, 1) to trim those. While that works for smaller numbers, somewhat larger numbers are output in a strange format that does not obey the rounding rules (IMHO):
I see an output of `1.330710e+04`. Obviously that number should be `13307.1`; in the format shown, there are actually two fractional digits displayed.
Is there a way to get more beautiful formatting? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: try `options(digits=10)`

Comment: The docs say the default is `7`, but when I change it to `7` the output is correct (when using interactive `print()`), also. It seems that `digits` even overrides the fractional digits `round()` returns. Is there any precise documentation on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
> format(round(345678998766.01))
[1] "3.45679e+11"

> format(round(345678998766.01), digits = 10)
[1] "345678998766"

> format(round(mean(c(345678998766.01, 345678998766.01))))
[1] "3.45679e+11"

> format(round(mean(c(345678998766.01, 345678998766.01))), digits = 10)
[1] "345678998766"
```

Comment: One related question: Which function is used by R for implicit output (i.e.: If I enter `1+2`)? `print`,  `format`, or something else?